# issue with url parameters in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

```
RewriteRule ^/pages/topic\.php?tag=$1 /topics/([^/]+) [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^topics/([^/]+)/?$  /pages/topic.php?tag=$1 [END]
```

My problem is with the 301 redirect, I believe the problem is with the `tag=$1` and `/([^/]+)` I'm not entirely sure I've done this correctly, My desired result is that when the user navigates to `/pages/topic.php?tag=cryptocom` that the user is then redirected to `/topics/cryptocom/` Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please confirm that user is hitting ink like: `http://localhost:80/pages/topic.php?tag=cryptocom` in browser which needs to be changed to `http://localhost:80/topics/cryptocom/` in browser?

Comment: yeah thats correct, the url `http://localhost:80/pages/topic.php?tag=cryptocom` works and so does `http://localhost:80/topics/cryptocom` but i want when when the user hits the url `http://localhost:80/pages/topic.php?tag=cryptocom` to be redirected to the shortened version. thankyou

Comment: _"I believe the problem is with the tag=$1 and /([^/]+) I'm not entirely sure I've done this correctly"_ - no, that part is not correct at all - RewriteRule matches the pattern against the path component of the URL only, you can not check query string contents in a RewriteRule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown attempts/samples, please try following htaccess rules file.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/pages/([^.]*)\.php\?tag=(\S+)\s
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^topics/([^/]+)/?$  /pages/topic.php?tag=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: i dont understand how this answer works - let me try

Comment: @Lewis, its a tested code, it works fine on my localhost, kindly do check from your end and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: Thankyou works a charm!